# How to set dataTextFormatString of @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date-format

In my `MVC` view I am displaying `dropDownList`. It contains list of dates which I retrieved from the database. Dates are in both date and time combination.I do not need to show that time .

How to set display format for that. My coding like below;

view

```
@Html.DropDownList("regdate");
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.regdate= new SelectList(regdatesList);
```

How to use `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` kind of a thing to solve this?

EDIT
Query use to get the dates

```
var regdatesList=from s in datahandler.students  
            select s
```

Comment: How are you populating `regdatesList`?

Comment: using linq query on the database.

Comment: That query is pretty relevant to this question.

Comment: it does nothing. basically a select query. anyway I have updated the question

Comment: Have you added that as an attribute to the property that's displayed in the drop down?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at the controller.

Your CSHTML:

```
@Html.DropDownList("regdate", YourController.Get_List(), " ")
```

Your Controller:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Get_List()
        {
            var selectList = (from c in table
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = c.Date_In_Table.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY"),
                            Value = c.Date_In_Table
                        }
                    );

            return selectList;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regdatesList = datahandler.students.Select(d => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = d.ToShortDateString(),
    Value = d.ToShortDateString()
});
```

[ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) is `culture-sensitive`, meaning it will adjust the display of the date depending on your users' culture settings.  That means your users always get an appropriate representation of the date, based on their culture.  If you want to ensure that the date is in `dd/MM/yyyy` format for everyone, no matter where they're from, then Douglas's answer is the way to go.

The `Text` property represents the text that will be displayed for each item in the list.  The `Value` property represents the value you want to associate with that item, so you may either want to leave that as the date or set it to some other appropriate field from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   String myDate = myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```